# onChange not working if first click is on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Not sure if this is something that can be fixed or if I need to look at other options but here is my issue.

I have a text input box and when text is entered it triggers an ajax function and writes data to a database. This works fine if I write in the box then click/tab out of the box. There is also a submit button on the page, if I type in the input box and click the button the ajax isn't triggered.

```
<form name="cart_quantity" 
action="http://127.0.0.1/360v3/product_info.php? 
products_id=20%7B3%7D28&amp;action=add_product" method="post" role="form"> 
<input name="formid" type="hidden" 
value="e0cfde314f5da74abe48a886de30aea6c996c334cd40521209a181caba46b763" 
class="form-control">

<div class="row is-product">
<div class="col-sm-12 cm-pi-modular">
<div class="row">


<div class="col-sm-4">

<div class="col-sm-12 text-right mt-2 pi-text-input">

  <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-form-label col-sm-3 text-left text-sm-right">Name 
</label>
   <div class="col-sm-9">
       <div id="tagit">
<input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name">           
           <input name="id[3]" type="hidden" class="form-control" 
id="input_3" value="30">
       </div>
      </div>
      </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).on( 'blur',  '#tagit #name', function(){
    name = $('#name').val();
pID = $('#pID').val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "ext/scripts/textAttribute.php", 
    data: "name=" + name + "&pID=" + pID + "&type=insert",
    cache: true, 
    success: function(data){
      $("#input_3").val(data);
    }
  });
  
});
</script>

<div class="col-sm-12 pi-buy-button mt-2">
<button data-has-attributes="1" data-in-stock="0" data-product-id="20" 
class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg btn-product-info btn-buy" 
type="submit"> <span class="fas fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"> 
</span> Add To Cart</button><input name="products_id" type="hidden" 
value="20" class="form-control"></div>

  </div></div>

</div>
</div>

</form>
```

Contents of textAttribute.php has been omitted as I do not believe it is relevant to the issue.

So far I have changed the onChange to onBlur with the same issue and onInput however this triggers the function for each keystroke.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I have changed the onChange to onInput and am now looking at ways to limit the number of times it runs to just one using timers or similar.

Comment: Could you please show us all the HTML markup? So including the button? Also: Is there an enclosing form element?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but we need further informations: Is there an enclosing form element wich includes your input fields and your button? Like `<form><input><button></button></form>`

Comment: If your button submits the form the normal way, then the browser will cancel all still running JS code / background requests at some point, because normal form submission means "load a new result page and display that instead of the current document." But if the text field and the button are in the same form, then the normal form submission would include the text field value as well, so you could simply process it on the receiving end together with the rest of the form data, it would not really _need_ AJAX in this case then ...

Comment: @CBroe the submit button runs a different function

Comment: Then add the code for that, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi if you are looking on how to limit it, there are so called "debounce" functions.

Basically you can limit how fast some actions are going to be processed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).